# How to change text to value in data tables

Tags: datatables

Hi I am trying to export my values into excel but some of them are converting to text I don't know why I am passing integers but the exported excel file is converting them into integer. Is there any way to convert them into integer ?

```
  table = $('#OriTable').dataTable({
    responsive: false,
    orderClasses: false,
    aaData: json["data"],
    deferRender:    true,
    stateSave:      true,
    bPaginate:      false,
    searching:      false,
    aaSorting:      false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
  });
```

Thanks.

**Update**

Attached the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnDYR.png

data examples:

[1, "Finca", 6.371, 2378167.48, 0.13]

[2, "Diner", 5.573, 75643343.6, 4.27]

Comment: What is in `json["data"]`? Can you add a sample to the question?

Comment: I have observed one thing while opening the file in excel there is an invisible single quote which can only be seen on the top bar.

Comment: A single quote at the start of the cell value means the value will be [displayed as text](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/single-quote-at-start-of-text-cell-not-shown/56376140-05c9-408f-852f-a30e4b2d9d27). What is in `json["data"]`? Can you add a sample to the question?

Comment: I have added an image with sample values do you need it as text ?

Comment: Yes - please don't post images of code/data. Please post as formatted text. But what you show in your image is not JSON - it's just columns of data. That will not help to get your question answered.

Comment: Also, I note that some of the data is a list of numbers separated by commas, for example: `92,02,316.53`. That will be interpreted as text, because of how the data is formatted. Is that an Indian lakh number, by any chance? If so, then that is probably your problem.

Comment: It is Indian lakh number but it's causing for some numbers only not for every numbers.

Comment: Show us what's inside `json["data"]`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I have updated it with some sample values.